# Showing no non-zero element is nilpotent in a ring.

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose that R is a ring in which $a^{2}=0$ implies that a=0
Show that R has no-non-zero nilpotent element

Attempt:

Recall that an element x of a ring R is called nilpotent IF there exists some positive integer n such that $x^{n}=0$

> Attempt:
>
> Suppose that R has a non-zero nilpotent element.
> Then, $a^{n}=0$ for some $a\neq 0 \in R$ for some positive n.

Here's where I am stuck. If I can show $n=2$, I can arrive at a contradiction. But how do I do so?

Comment: Obvious fact: $n$ must be odd.

Answer (score 4):

Sketch: It is obvious that the smallest possible $n$ must be odd in your set-up because if $n$ were even, then $n=2k$ and $(a^k)^2=0$, so $a^k=0$.

Assume that $n\geq 3$ and consider $a^{n+1}$.  Let $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$.  This is zero because $a^{n+1}=a^n\cdot a^1=0\cdot a^1=0$.  But then, $(a^{k+1})^2=0$, so, by assumption $a^{k+1}=0$.  This is a contradiction because $k+1<n$.

A specific example: Suppose that $a^3=0$ (and $3$ is the smallest power of $a$ for which $a^n=0$).  Then $a^4=a^3\cdot a^1=0\cdot a^1=0$.  Moreover, $a^4=(a^2)^2=0$, so by assumption, $a^2=0$, a contradiction because this is a smaller power of $a$ which is equal to $0$.

Comment: sorry for the wrong answer, my oversight

Comment: You can't use the inverse. It's not a ring with 1. Thus the outer operation, must not have an inverse.

Comment: Patrick is correct that this is not a ring with inverse by virtual of the fact that the unity property is not stated.

Comment: But it's stated that $b^2 = 0 \Rightarrow b=0$ ... Just noticed... Overlooked it.

Comment: There is no use of an inverse here, all the powers are positive.  Since $n\geq 3$, $n-1\geq 2$ this is just a lower power. @PatrickAbraham

Comment: You used the fact that $b^2 = 0 \Rightarrow b=0$, as I said, I overlooked this important feature of the ring.

Comment: I do not understand the part onward where you assume that n is greater or equal to 3. You claimed n must be odd. I'm not sure why you do not express n=2k-1. What follows in your argument is really confusing.

Comment: I made some edits to try to make this clearer.  Note that when you assume $n$ is odd, it is not always helpful to replace $n$ by $2k+1$.  The idea is that for any power $m$ greater than or equal to $n$, $a^m=0$, so make a situation where $m$ is even and use the given property.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, it's the powers of 2 for the exponent, i.e. $a^{2^n} = 0$, which give the implication of $a = 0$ only and not just the even numbered exponents. But here's my proof:

By the contrapositive, $a \neq 0 \Longrightarrow a^2 \neq 0 \Longrightarrow a^4 \neq 0 \Longrightarrow a^{2^n} \neq 0$ for all positive integers $n > 1$. If an element $a$ were nilpotent, then $a^m = 0$ for some fixed $m$. Since we can always find an $n$ such that $2^n > m$, choose such an $n$ and we have $0 = a^m \cdot a^{2^n - m} = a^{2^n}$, which is a contradiction. Thus, no nonzero element of $R$ is nilpotent.